# Float left, fluid layout

Tags: css, css-float

Is there a way of closing the gaps between elements without using column or rows?

I've build this

```
<div class="box">
    <p>Short height</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>Something</li>
        <li>To</li>
        <li>make</li>
        <li>height</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <p>Short height</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <p>Oh no! I'm not in the place where I should me! DX </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
    width:30%;
    margin:0% 1.6666%;
    float:left;
}
```

How can I make the elements stop starting after the height of the previous longest element. Not even too sure how to word it!?

So instead of starting underneath the tallest, the 4th element should start underneath the element exactly above it. 
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The margin attribute in your css is doing the problem. Just remove the margin. Please let me know if it is the workable solution.

Comment: oh my bad, no it still happens, I just made an error :d

Comment: forgot the 0% on top and bottom, I still don't get the look I want. K K's answer is close but I'd like CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you could try either having them in the same box to keep them together or try removing the margin

here is a fiddle with the margin removed

https://jsfiddle.net/49uzyskh/

css

```
.box{
    width:30%;
    /*margin:1.6666%;*/
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: the element is on the right and not the left because the middle element's height is higher than 3rd element

Comment: so where would you like the "oh no..." to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this layout:

[http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/infinite-scroll.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20160108184111/http://desandro.github.io:80/masonry/demos/infinite-scroll.html)

If yes,
you can refer the plugin here:
[Masonry Plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20160102055340/http://desandro.github.io:80/masonry/docs/intro.html)

You can also refer this plugin :[Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html)

Comment: That's the look I want but I didn't want to use a plugin. I could write the javascript myself but would rather use just css. Thanks for the help though n_n